# Converting Object to Object array pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

I have an object that has data(s) now I want to transform it in specific pattern.

Below is my object

```
{
    _groups: ["d1830f7c-12ac-4abf-bc03-f0b70e26f8f2", "d0348b51-dcaa-2227-f0ff-912b27100aee"],
    _eror: "",
    number: "",
    seen_days: Infinity, // dont count this if this is Infinity or make add it
    address: "",
    status: "ACTIVE"
}
```

Now if I want to convert it into below pattern.

```
 [
        {
            "field": "status",
            "value": "ACTIVE",
            "operator": "equal"
        },
        {
            "field": "_groups",
            "value": "d1830f7c-12ac-4abf-bc03-f0b70e26f8f2",
            "operator": "equal"
        },
        {
            "field": "_groups",
            "value": "d0348b51-dcaa-2227-f0ff-912b27100aee",
            "operator": "equal"
        }
]







const convert = (obj) => {
  const arr = [];
  obj._groups.forEach((el) => {
    arr.push({
      field: "_groups",
      value: el,
      operator: "equal",
    });
  });
  console.log(obj)
  
  var key = Object.keys(obj);
  var value = obj[key];
  arr.push({
    field: value,
    value: obj.status,
    operator: "equal",
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Currently trying this function but this isn't working as expected.

- Include only those fields which has data, exclude other fields also Infinity
- The object that needs to be convert to array object is dynamic, every time the data will be different but it needs to be convert into the above pattern(Array object pattern).
- Motive is to match the pattern of array object with providing dynamic object with data.(THE DATA WILL BE DIFFRENT, BUT it should be converted into the pattern as mentioned.)

Comment: data is already plural :P the singular of data is datum.

Comment: Please include how you are solving it currently. Your current code. And where you are stuck.

Comment: where is the operator property coming from? is it always just "equal" or what?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Yes it will be always equal, Also I have updated the question with function I have been trying to set it. PLease help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const x = {
    _groups: ["d1830f7c-12ac-4abf-bc03-f0b70e26f8f2", "d0348b51-dcaa-2227-f0ff-912b27100aee"],
    _eror: "",
    number: "",
    seen_days: Infinity, // dont count this if this is Infinity or make add it
    address: "",
    status: "ACTIVE"
}
const result = []
createObj = (item,value) => {
           const temp = { }
            temp["field"] = item
            temp["value"] =  value
            temp["operator"] = "equal"
            result.push(temp)
}

Object.keys(x).forEach(item => {

     if(x[item] && x[item] !== Infinity){
        if(Array.isArray(x[item])){
           
          x[item].forEach(record => {
            createObj(item, record)
          })
          
     } else {
           createObj(item, x[item])
        }
    
     }
     
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: very similar like my code, we got similar thinking :)

Comment: it is true, developer think same.

Answer (score 0):

- Initialise an empty Array
- Get your keys from your object first.
- Loop your keys and check if value of the object is array using the key, if it is Array, loop that and push inside the Array.
- If value is not array, same thing just push inside the Array using your schema format.

Below code is tested.

> ```
> var sample = {
>       _groups: ["d1830f7c-12ac-4abf-bc03-f0b70e26f8f2", "d0348b51-dcaa-2227-f0ff-912b27100aee"],
>       _eror: "",
>       number: "",
>       seen_days: Infinity,
>       address: "",
>       status: "ACTIVE"
>     }
>
> let targetArray = [];
> ```

> ```
> const keys = Object.keys(sample)
>   .filter(v => !!sample[v] && sample[v] !== Infinity);
>
> keys.forEach(key => {
>   if (Array.isArray(sample[key])) {
>     sample[key].forEach((sampleKey => {
>       targetArray.push({
>         field: key,
>         value: sampleKey,
>         operator: "equal"
>       })
>     }))
>   } else {
>     targetArray.push(
>       {
>         field: key,
>         value: sample[key],
>         operator: "equal"
>       }
>     )
>   }
> })
>
>
> console.log(targetArray)
> ```